# Slow Performance of Complex Operations

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-asynctask

Folks.

I've designed a currency exchange application in which i got all exchange rates once at application start and create own SQLite DB then easily pull them into the converter interface. I've designed the change to be done in my Edittext onTextChanged listener with a textwatcher and all works perfectly.  I've also have a listview in the same activity for Favorite exchange rates and its also has to be calculated every time the edittext changes. My main problem is that I've got a slow performance and freeze issues in my application. I've tried to implement Asynctask to process the calculations but it didn't help me and i still get the performance issues. Hereunder my code for your reference. Please Advice !!

Text Watcher :

```
valval.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {



        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {

        }

        public void afterTextChanged(final Editable s)

        {

            Calculate();

        }
    });
```

Calculate :

```
private void Calculate()

{

    curs = mDb.query(MyDbHelper.TABLE_NAME, columns, MyDbHelper.COL_Common
            + "=" + "?", new String[] { From[xxxto] + From[xxxfrom] },
            null, null, null);
    cursD = mDb.query(MyDbHelper.TABLE_NAME, columns, MyDbHelper.COL_Common
            + "=" + "?", new String[] { From[xxxfrom] + From[xxxto] },
            null, null, null);

    curs.moveToFirst();

    cursD.moveToFirst();

    double selection = curs.getDouble(curs
            .getColumnIndex(MyDbHelper.COL_Currone));

    double selection2 = cursD.getDouble(cursD
            .getColumnIndex(MyDbHelper.COL_Currone));

    Long myNum = Long.parseLong(valval.getText().toString().trim());

    double myNum3 = Double.parseDouble(new DecimalFormat("#.######").format(myNum * selection2));


    valval2.setText(String.valueOf(myNum3));



    Cursor B = mDb.query(MyDbHelper.TABLE_NAME, columns,
            MyDbHelper.COL_CurrFavor + " LIKE ? And "
                    + MyDbHelper.COL_Currsecond + " LIKE ?", new String[] {
                    "YES", "EUR" }, null, null, null);


    for (int s = 0; s < B.getCount() - 1; s++)

    {
        B.moveToPosition(s);

        String ZVZV = B.getString(0);

        int BSBS = B.getInt(9);


        Cursor curcur = mDb.query(MyDbHelper.TABLE_NAME, columns, MyDbHelper.COL_Common
                + "=" + "?", new String[] { From[xxxfrom] + From[BSBS-1] },
                null, null, null);

        curcur.moveToFirst();

        double calcal = curcur.getDouble(6);



        ContentValues args = new ContentValues();

        double formattedNumber = Double.parseDouble(new DecimalFormat("#.######").format(myNum * calcal));

        args.put(MyDbHelper.COL_Currsum,formattedNumber );

        mDb.update(MyDbHelper.TABLE_NAME, args, "_id =" + ZVZV, null);



    }

    cursm.requery();

}
```

Comment: Do you really need to use a data base for this ? I'm sure that an SQL expert will tell you that your queries are inefficient, but why not use shared preferences ?

Comment: Because i have around 4700 row in my Database according to the exchange rates and i don't think i have such experience in the shared preferences section. Any help would be appreciated !

Comment: Can you just break that down a bit e.g. 470 currencies and 10 entries for each or 47 currencies and 100 for each ? Does any other app use your database ?

Comment: I will try to find a way to do that and my DB is not shared to any other applications.

Comment: I'm just trying to understand the structure of your data. Basically, I would seriously consider using arrays to do this, and if you need to share the data between activities then use shared prefs (simple to use). As I said, a database expert might be able to tell you how to improve your queries - in the absence of specialist knowledge - divide your queries into simpler ones and you might be able to spot the problem yourself.

Comment: I will try to split my DB into 2 DBs as I pull all my queries from the    master DB and see if it make any performance differences.Also any comments from SQLite experts would be much appreciated ! Thanks for your help ! :)

Comment: SQLite isn't very optimized, so things like "LIKE" probably aren't optimized. Can you search by exact key instead?

Comment: Thanks! I will have a try without "Like" and will let you know.

Comment: I've changed it a little bit as suggested and it doesnt make any differences in the performance

Cursor B = mDb.rawQuery("select * from "
    + MyDbHelper.TABLE_NAME + " where " + MyDbHelper.COL_CurrFavor + " = ? AND  "
    + MyDbHelper.COL_Currsecond + " = ?", new String[] { "YES", "EUR" });

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I can imagine of from your description is, you're most likely having 2 EditTexts, where user only input to first, and you will sync the converted value for second, is this true? If it is, may I suggest you not to perform the operation right after every text change?

You may want to do `Calculate()` only after user finishes his input, perhaps one second delay of calculation is acceptable?

```
// Declare these as class variable
private Handler handler = new Handler();
private Runnable calculateRunnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        Calculate();
    }
}
```

As for your TextWatcher, change this

```
public void afterTextChanged(final Editable s) {
    handler.removeCallbacks(calculateRunnable);
    handler.postDelayed(calculateRunnable, 1000);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Chor for your suggestion it's very useful. I think my complex operations are starting from defining "Cursor B" until the end. I've marked them as /* and found all other transactions are pretty good with a good performance. I think i should have a look into it.

Comment: Usually db writing operations (Disk IO) will costs you fair amount of processing resource, not to mention you seems like doing it on every text change, minimizing the update should gives you better responsiveness